# django deployment with java and c++

Tags: c++, django, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I have created a django app that contains c++ for some of the views as well as a java library. How would I deploy this app? What kind of hosting service allows for multiple languages? I have looked at EC2, GAE, and several platforms (like heroku) but I can't seem to find a definitive solution.

I have never deployed anything to the web so a simple explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: GAE won't work, EC2 or any service where you have root access to a virtual linux box should be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PaaS stuff is probably not your best bet. If you want the scalability and associated buzzwords(muh 99.9999999999% availability because my servers are hosted in a parallel dimension without electrical storms, power outages, hurricanes, earthquakes, or nuclear holocausts) that comes with hosting your application on a huge web company's platform, check out IaaS(Infrastructure as a service) systems like [Google's Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/)  or [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/). With these you just get a virtual server (or servers), running your Linux distro of choice, and you can install and run whatever you please on them without being constrained to a specific platform like App Engine or Heroku(where you have to basically write your app to specifically run on that platform). If you plan on consuming a ton of bandwidth/resources from the get-go, you will almost certainly get a better deal using a dedicated server(s) from a small company.
Interested in what specifically you are executing C++ for in a Django view. Image/video processing?

Answer (score 0):

Well. Deployment is not really something where a simple explanation helps much.

First I would check what the requirements to the operating system are (compilers, dependencies,…). That will maybe reduce the options quickly.

I guess that with a setup containing C++ & Java artifacts, the usual PaaS (GaE, Heroku,…) offerings will not be sufficient because *they* define the stack. And a mixture of Python/C++/Java is rather uncommon I'd say.

Choosing an IaaS offering (EC2, …) may be an option. There you can run your whole self-defined stack and have the possibility of *easier* scaling. 
Hosting the application on your own server(s) is also always possible. Check your data protection regulations to find out if it's not even a requirement.

There are a lot of ways to get the Django application to run. The Django documentation has some [information about deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/). If you have certain special requirements, [uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/) may be a good application server.

You may also want a web server in front of the application. Possibilities range from using uwsgi's built-in http server or using e.g. [Nginx with uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

All in all every component of the whole "deployment" has hundereds of bells and whistels and it's not easy to give advice without knowing specific requirements and properties of the system itself. You'll also probably need a database you have to *deploy*.

---

But before deploying it to the web, it's also important to have a solid build process to assemble all the parts. And not only on the development machine. With three languages involved this should be the first step solve. If it easily and *automagically* deploys in a development environment, moving it to a server is easier.